# What were the selling points of the Atari 800 over the 400?

Tags: history, keyboards, atari-800, cost, atari-400

Apparently when the two Atari 8-bit machines were released, the 400 outsold the 800 2 to 1, which is unsurprising considering they were priced at approximately $500 and $1000 respectively.

Indeed, the surprise is that the ratio was not higher. Granted the 800 had an extra cartridge slot; that doesn't jump out as being a very important feature; it at least looks like one in three customers were willing to pay an extra $500 largely or entirely for a better keyboard. Which would be very logical for a productivity machine, but more surprising for a machine whose primary selling point was games.

Were those one in three customers really paying for the better keyboard, or did the 800 have some other selling point I'm not taking into account?

Comment: The 400 came with 16k RAM and initially it was not that simple to upgrade like the 800 was. I remember upgrading mine by soldering on a daughterboard. Eventually Atari released an “official” upgrade board.

Comment: Did the 400 have basic?  I seem to remember basic being on a cartridge...

Comment: @Geo... the 400 and 800 needed a cartridge for BASIC, but IIRC it was provided with the computer (*i.e.* not an extra purchase).

Comment: Don’t underestimate the keyboard factor. Having grown up with an Atari 400, I can testify that its membrane keyboard is truly awful, and I would have been delighted to have an 800 instead...

Comment: I had a 400 and didn't mind the keyboard at all. I didn't find it all that different from modern low-profile keyboards and could type quite fast on it. My particular machine had the added bonus that the glue under the area of the control and left shift came undone and those "keys" bubbled upward to form domes.

Comment: Didn't own either one of them, but I had opportunity to type on both. My memory of the experience is much faded, but I guess I recall the 400 keyboard having virtually no tactile feedback, which made touch-typing near impossible.  Maybe I could have learned with practice, but I had access to other computers, and I never tried the Ataris again.

Comment: I own two 400's, an 800 and a few 600XL's and 800XL's.  Out of all of them, the 800 has them all beat.  That machine is so solid.  The keyboard is great.  While the 800XL is superior (64 KiB RAM, GTIA 256 colors), the 800 is just so nice to use.  Back in the day, if you had the extra money, it would have been worth it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a few improvements that made the 800 more valuable

```
                           Candy     Coleen
                           (400)     (800)
RAM (original design 1979)   4 KiB     8 KiB
RAM (first delivered 1980)   8 KiB    16 KiB
Maximum RAM               (48) KiB    48 KiB (*1)
RAM (later models    1982)  16 KiB    48 KiB
ROM Slots                    1         2     (*2)
Expansion Slots              1         3
Free Slots                   0         2
Keyboard                   Membrane  Full Stroke
```

*1 - RAM on the 400 could only be extended by replacing the existing board after opening the case.

*2 - ROM cartridges where meant to carry (up to) 8 KiB each. The 'left' slot was mapped at $8000, while the 'right' was mapped at $A000. A 'left' cartridge could also fill the whole 16 KiB.

When speaking about sales numbers, it might be worth  noting that according to Curt  Vendels book only about 35,000 400 *and* 800 where sold until December 1980. So the 'big' difference shrinks to more reasonable numbers - not enough to really show a trend.

Comment: That last line can't be emphasized enough. The Atari 400 "chicklet" keyboard was gawdaful. Ever seen anyone selling one of those for a consumer PC clone? No? There's a reason why.

Comment: @T.E.D. Membrane keyboards (chicklet is the pocket calculator style as shown with the PET) were a lot. Just think the incredible numbers of the ZX80/81 and TS1000 sold.

Comment: Not in the US they didn't. I never quite understood why folks elsewhere were willing to put up with those horrible keyboards. Perhaps money was just a lot more tight there, or perhaps they just wanted to play games and didn't want to program. Whatever it was, ick.

Comment: @T.E.D. The Timex Sinclair was **only** sold in the US. And there where others, like Magnavox Odyssey2 and several other in/for the US market.

Comment: The Sinclair was also sold in the UK and Portugal, and only sold 600k units in the US in the **ONE** year it was in production. That's effectively nothing in that market. By comparison, the competing C64 sold in the neighborhood of 15 million and the Atari 800 4 million. I think I once saw an Oddysey in a magazine back in the day, but I never once even saw one in a store.

Comment: That's why I mentioned the **Timex** Sinclair, which was produced especially and only for the US. With 600k units in one year in the US it was quite competive to the Commodore. For 1982 that's the C64 sold about ~8-900k. So with these numbers the TS1000 was second C64 and way ahead of any competiton. Not a nice product them. Even if it might seam so from a personal view. _BTW: the C64 sold about 12.5m units over a time of ~9 years._ See Michael Steils well founded calculations  https://www.pagetable.com/?p=547

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79509/discussion-between-t-e-d-and-raffzahn).

Answer (score 6):

The Atari 800 allowed a maximum of 48k of RAM, vs the 16k maximum in the Atari 400. After 1980, both models shipped with maximum RAM - so you were getting three times as much memory with the 800. (Details are on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_8-bit_family#400/800_release).)

Comment: Plus a better keyboard, an additional ROM slot, user-accessible RAM slots, and better video output options (per the wiki).  The 400 was marketed as a home computer/game machine and the 800 as a professional computer.

Comment: Good point! I had overlooked the extra memory; that's very important.

Comment: @AlexHajnal: Was the 400 a computer, or a *Star Raiders* console?

Comment: @supercat I'm not clear what you're asking.  The 400 could be used as a general-purpose computer and not just as a dedicated games console.

Comment: @AlexHajnal: To what extent were people able to overcome the limitations of the Atari 400's keyboard, making it a practical computer, and to what extent was the keyboard mainly usable for *Star Raiders*, a game which could use even a crummy keyboard to great effect?  In theory, the Atari 400 could do most of the things the 800 could, but how many machines ended up being used that way in practice?

Comment: @supercat  I have no answer for that.  Sorry.

Comment: @supercat, the 400 keyboard was fully functional, it was just “uncomfortable” to use. The 400 was my first computer and I typed in many programs from Compute and Antic on that keyboard. I wrote many of my own programs, in Basic and later Action! and C/65 and assembler. And I learned how to touch type in school so I was pretty fast. You just felt like you had no fingerprints after a long session...

Comment: @mannaggia: I guess one could get used to it.  I remember it seemed pretty bad.  I thought my VIC-20 keyboard felt pretty wonderful compared with many of its other competitors.

Comment: Oh you never got used to it... I hated it. But I didn’t have the money for a 800 and all my friends had C64 and I was (and still am somewhat) a contrarian... though I gave in and got an iPhone... getting old...

Comment: The additional ROM slot was effectively useless. I believe there were a total of three or four cartridges for it, ever. Monkey Wrench II was the best.